# PDO - Extending vs Injection

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli, dependency-injection, extends

I've recently migrated from using MySQL to PDO. Originally, I had a class which was a wrapper for the MySQLi object, providing some basic functions and settings I used a lot.

I want to do the same thing for PDO. I want PDO to always throw exceptions and I also found im mostly dealing with associative arrays so I made a class to provide this by extending PDO to save constantly writing the same code across multiple projects:

```
class noc_pdo extends PDO {

function __construct($dsn, $user, $pass) {
    parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass, array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}

function returnQueryAsAssociativeArray($query) {
    $stmt = $this->query($query);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    return $result;
}

function returnPreparedStmtAsAssociativeArray($preparedStmt, $parameters) {
    $preparedStmt->execute($parameters);
    $result = $preparedStmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $preparedStmt->closeCursor();
    return $result;
}
}
```

It's likely I will continue to expand as I go so I'd rather try and get this right (and start good habits) before it's too late so the question I am posing if it's acceptable to extend in this case or should I have just had this class initiate a PDO object instead? Perhaps both of these solutions are terrible and should be scraped for a more commonly used design?

Comment: *Perhaps both of these solutions are terrible*: **Yes**!. *scraped for a more commonly used design?*: **[tag:PDO] already works like that**.

Comment: Looking forward, how should I add my commonly used functions for sharing across projects?